# Lipschitz continuity of the integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

For any metric space $(A,a)$ and any real-valued function $f$ on $A$ we define its Lipchitz constant as
$$
  \|f\|_a:=\sup_{x\neq x'}\frac{|f(x) - f(x')|}{a(x,x')}.
$$

Consider a metric space $(X,d)$ and let $X^2$ be the product space endowed with a product metric
$$
  d^2((x,y),(x',y')):=\max(d(x,x'),d(y,y')).
$$
Suppose that $P$ is a stochastic kernel on $X$ and let the function $f:X^2\to \mathbb R$ satisfy $\|f\|_{d^2}\leq 1$. Are there any conditions on $P$ to assure that
$$
  g(x):=\int_X f(x,y)P(x,\mathrm dy)
$$
also satisfies $\|g\|_d\leq 1$? Perhaps, $P:X\to\mathcal P(X)$ as a map that assigns to a state a probability distribution has to be Lipschitz continuous in some kind of metric on $\mathcal P(X)$, the set of all Borel probability distributions on $X$?